# Java Passing a char from a method back to main

Tags: java

I'm writing a method that checks that 1 of 3 letters has been entered.
The problem is I can't get the method to return the char.

The char variable in initially read into Scanner and entered into an array.

Here is where it is read in,

```
            //get house Type and send into array
            System.out.println("Property " +numProperty+ " : Terraced, Semi-Detached, Detached: (T/S/D)");
            houseType [i] = readLetter(input.next().charAt(0));
            input.next().charAt(0);
```

And this is the method readLetter

```
    public static char readLetter(char input){


        if(input != 'T'||input != 't'||input != 'S'||input != 's'||input != 'D'||input != 'd')
            System.out.println("Invalid input! Enter option T, S or D? ");

        else    

        return input;       

    }
```

The error is

> The method must return a result of type char.

Comment: The condition in `readLetter` is always true - you mean `&&` instead of `||`. But also, you need to return a value when the letter is "invalid" as well as when it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static char readLetter(char input){


    if(input != 'T'&& input != 't'&& input != 'S'&&input != 's'&&input != 'D'&&input != 'd')
    {    
        System.out.println("Invalid input! Enter option T, S or D? ");
        return 0; //or something that signals invalid input
    }
    else    
    {
       return input;
    }       

}
```

Comment: You can't return -1 - `char` is an unsigned type.

Answer (score 1):

In the `readLetter` method you must return value in both cases, for example:

```
public static char readLetter(char input) {
  if(input != 'T' && input != 't' && input != 'S' && input != 's' && input != 'D' && input != 'd') {
    System.out.println("Invalid input! Enter option T, S or D? ");
    return 0;  
  } else {
    return input;
  }
}
```

This will return 0 if `input != 'T' && input != 't' && input != 'S' && input != 's' && input != 'D' && input != 'd'`. You need to handle that in your main method, something like this:

```
System.out.println("Property " +numProperty+ " : Terraced, Semi-Detached, Detached: (T/S/D)");
char ch = readLetter(input.next().charAt(0));
if ( ch != 0 ) {
  // the input was valid
  houseType[i] = readLetter(input.next().charAt(0));
}
input.next().charAt(0);
```

**Update:** as someone noticed your condition `input != 'T'||input != 't'||input != 'S'||input != 's'||input != 'D'||input != 'd'` will always return true (ie. your input will always be illegal) but the fix is to replace `||` into `&&` (change ORs into ANDs).

I edited the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the case when the user enters an invalid value.

What the method is supposed to return in this case?

IMO, this method should return true or false indicating wheter the passed input is valid(T,S or D) or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this:

```
if(input != 'T'||input != 't'||input != 'S'||input != 's'||input != 'D'||input != 'd')
     System.out.println("Invalid input! Enter option T, S or D? ");
else    
    return input;
```

so since you are not using **{}**, then the code is returning only if the condition is not met.

so your compiler complains since that method is not always returning a char...